# Ubuntu - Django Haystack and Solr Integration Error

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I have read these two tutorials for building an search app.

1. Installing Solr and django-haystack on Ubuntu with OpenJDK, [here](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/installing-solr-and-django-haystack-on-ubuntu-with-openjdk/)
2. Django – Haystack – Solr — Setup Guide, [here](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/django-haystack-solr-setup-guide/)

but when i come to:

> Configure django-haystack, set up the search index classes according
>   to the docs
>
> http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#configuration
>
> Add the required solr fields to settings.py (solr server location)

I get this error (when trying to import haystack too):

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("You must define the HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting before using
         the search framework.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You must define the HAYSTACK_SITECONF 
          setting before using the search framework.
```

Importing haystack in python, error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_haystack-1.2.7-py2.6.egg/haystack
     /__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You must define the HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting before 
       using the search framework.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You must define the HAYSTACK_SITECONF 
           setting before using the search framework.
```

I have installed haystack with `sudo easy_install https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/zipball/v1.2.7`.

My django version: 1.4

**UPDATE:**

If you have troubles like this error when importing haystack:

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

try to import in your project as `./manage.py shell` rather than than `import haystack`.

Comment: What are you getting hung up on? Did you define `HAYSTACK_SITECONF` in settings.py?

Comment: @chriss i didnt define HAYSTACK_SITECONF i have defined HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS, instead. because of installing Haystack 1.2.7.

Comment: Haystack 1.2.7 doesn't use `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` -- that's for Haystack 2.0+. The Haystack documentation defaults to the development version, *not* the current PyPi release. Haystack 2.0 is perfectly usable if you want to go that route, though. I use it myself. You just have to clone it from Github.

Comment: @chris i hope that is true. and how can ı clone Haystack 2.0 from Github? there is a master branch which downloads v.1.2...

Comment: The easiest way is with pip: `pip install git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git#egg=django-haystack`, but otherwise, just download the "master" branch tarball.

Comment: @chris if you convert your comment to answer, i will make it accepted for anyone who face off this error... Django 1.4 works with Haystack 2.0. thanks for your helping..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haystack 1.2.7 doesn't use `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS`; only Haystack 2.0+ use that setting. The Haystack documentation defaults to the development version (2.0.0-beta, currently), not the current PyPi release (1.2.7), so you need to be careful which version of the docs you're looking at.

However, Haystack 2.0.0-beta is perfectly usable if you want to go that route, though. I use it myself. You just have to clone it from Github. The easiest way is with pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git#egg=django-haystack
```

Otherwise, just download the "master" branch tarball an install it manually with `python setup.py install`.